# TypoScriptFrontendController must be constructed with a valid SiteLanguage object or a resolved site in the current request as fallback. None given

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I've built a site in TYPO3 9 which was working just fine. Then decided to upgrade von TYPO3 10 (10.4.4), did the upgrade wizard, database check etc.
It all looked good. Now when I go to Web -> Page and inside the pagetree click the root page or a subpage of it, I get this error:

> Oops, an error occurred! TypoScriptFrontendController must be
> constructed with a valid SiteLanguage object or a resolved site in the
> current request as fallback. None given.
>
> More information regarding this error might be available online.

online link: https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1561583127
(there's nothing as of now)

The error makes me assume that I made an error with my site language.
When I go to Site Management -> Sites, everything seems to be configured correctly for my Default Language.

my config.yaml

```
base: 'https://dev.mywebsite.de/'
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: '404'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=11'
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ''
    flag: de
    languageId: '0'
    websiteTitle: 'Meine Website'
rootPageId: 1
routes: {  }
websiteTitle: 'My Website'
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: did you delete all caches via the install tool (Maintenance => Flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache)? Can you post the languages part of your config.yaml? Do you use a special `page.typeNum` setting?

Comment: @Peter Kraume Yes, I did delete all caches. I've added the config.yaml to my original post. I just use regular page.typeNum = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, problem solved, it was my fault afterall.

I had DCE installed and in one of my DCEs I had a backend template including `{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.example')}`
in it, I accidentally copy-pasted it from my frontend template and in TYPO3 9 it didn't cause any error. Now it does. Removed it and it all works fine!

Comment: But why would that cause a problem? Using a TS lib seems to be a fairly common thing. (I am currently facing the same problem, but I have no DCE in use; bootstrap_package, aimeos, mask)

Comment: @RobertWildling I just fixed a same issue. On my setup it was caused by the 'mask' extension. As with the OPs issue/solution, 'cObject' in a backend template was causing the problem. 
 A previous programmer made a 'mask_project' Extension for the Content Elements and one of the Backend Layouts in 'mask_project/Resources/Private/Mask/Backend/Templates' used a 'f:cObject' causing the error. I replaced it with static text to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when using `<f:cObject>` in the backend preview rendering of content elements in TYPO3v10.

In TYPO3 v11 this is again possible because the fluid view helper has been fixed with https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91511